# Screensaver program in tasm

Tags: screensaver, tasm, tsr

I am working on program of screensaver in tasm and i used int 21h

Code:

mov ah,35h

mov al,08h

int 21h

i searched about this and i found that 35h is used to transfer the control of the resident program to the interrupt number which is specified in al, here i have specified 08h which is a timer interrupt. But i found that it returns the address of interrupt in ES:Bx.
i am not able to understand that what is the meaning of ES:BX, Since the address of interrupt in a 16 bit address and both of the registers are of 16 bit. So, in which register the actual address is going.
Please help me as i am new to Assembly Language

Answer (score 0):

Intel 8086 used segmented memory model, where each pointer was stored in two registers: a segment register (CS/DS/ES/SS) and an offset register, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086#Segmentation